# Проблеммы с Qt, Qprocess

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

облазил все форумы, и все рaвно ничего не могу понять. Система моя проста, Qt скрипт по нажатии кнопки должен запускать исполняемый файл(Написан на питоне и скомпелирован в exe). Исполняемый файл при запуске(из консоли) нормально отрабатывает, а через Qt не запускается. Ниже выкладываю код. h файл не изменял он стандартный. Подскажите что я неправильно делаю ? Может какиую то отладку можно вставить? Заранее спасибо.

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "QProcess"
#include "QMessageBox"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::about(this,"test","test");
    QProcess *proc = new QProcess();

    proc->start("E:/QTproject/untitled9/PythonFile.exe");
    proc->waitForFinished();

    QString result=proc->readAllStandardOutput();
}
```

PythonFile.py

```
import pysftp
import sys

host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
username = "user"
password = "password"
port = 22
#hard-coded
cnOpts=pysftp.CnOpts()
cnOpts.hostkeys =None
with pysftp.Connection(host=host,port=port, username=username, password=password,cnopts=cnOpts) as sftp:
    sftp.get(r"D:\filesBD.txt",localpath=r".\filleBD.txt",preserve_mtime=True)
```

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что программа не запустилась? Брошено исключение? С каким содержимом? Что содержат `proc->state()` , `proc->error()` ?

Comment: вопрос поправил. срочно поменяйте пароль! и никогда не выкладывайте реальные логины/пароли

Comment: proc->state() пишет Running. proc->error() пишет UnknownError

Comment: Спасибо, добрые люди

Comment: попробуйте сделать `setWorkingDirectory`, перед `start`

Comment: Изменил директорию, никаких изменений

Comment: Попробовол этой строкой pr.start("cmd.exe /C start E:/QT/..../debug/ssh.exe"). Открывается консоль, закрывается и ничего не происходит. Может быть каких то прав на запись на диск нет ?